# Spark cassandra write options

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, spring-data-cassandra

I have an hdfs file that is quite large having 200 million records.I am trying to write this to cassandra using the datastax cassandra writer.

This works fine but takes 12 hours,i wanted to write this in batches or partitions so that i can keep loading cassandra table in a smaller transaction to finish the data laod.

can anyone help on this.

My approaches are below.

the simple approach that loads the data fine is as below that takes 12+ hours.

```scala
df.write .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") 
  .options(Map("table" -> "table_data", "keyspace" -> "ks_data"))
  .mode(SaveMode.Append) .option("confirm.truncate","true") .save()
```

---

I was trying to do some operation using foreachpartition for dataframe,need advise here how i can try this.

Also do i need to open connection to cassandra all the time inside foreachparititon?

Comment: what is the format of the file? Generally you don't need to go down to foreachpartition, etc. - Spark Cassandra Connector handles that the most efficient way

Comment: the file is an ORC File,however the size of the file  takes a long time to load,my idea was can i load the part files individually?

Comment: ORC file should be splittable, I belive that most of the problems with performance are on the Cassandra side. How big is the Cassandra cluster? Do you see timeouts, etc. in the Cassandra logs, also - dropped mutations, etc.? Do you see tasks failed on Spark side?